# After inserting an item into MongoDb, how do you get its ObjectID?

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, database

last inserted objectid, just like the one MYSQL has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the standard Python API, it returns the [`ObjectID`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) when you call [`insert`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.9%2B/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert).  Are you expecting/trying to get the `ObjectID` in some other manner?

Comment: I'm using pymongo.  theobjectid = datasets.insert(post)

is that right?

Comment: Yes, it will have a type of `ObjectID`, which encodes the BSON ObjectID data that Mongo uses.